# How to determine how many times an area was burnt?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, analysis, overlapping-features

In arcgis I want to find from various forests fires shp files how many times parts of a particular forest were burnt during the last 70 years. Is there a way to count overlapping polygons?

Comment: Are you trying to find such a dataset or do you have data and you are trying to do an analysis? Your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "various shp files?". Do you have data about the fires separately for every shp? What about satellite images of the area?? I don't fully understand your question. You can work with satellite images and analyze vegetation indexes as NDVI and NBR index.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have multiple independent polygon shapefiles of fires for a specific area, you can use the following workflow:

1. [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000) your shapefiles into one
2. Use the [Count Overlapping Polygons](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1dd4a6832b3d40b494dbf8521cc5134c) script tool

The resulting polygon shapefile will have a count associated with the shapefile, which you can then use in your symbology.

[image]